isomorphism between sheaves and pullbacks
Given a flat surjective morphism $\pi: X \to Y$, where both $X$ and $Y$ are smooth irreducible schemes, and $F$ a locally free sheaf on $X$ such that $R^i(\pi_*)(F) = 0$ for $i>0$, what additional conditions should I impose on $X$ or $Y$ or $\pi$ so that $F$ is isomorphic to $\pi^*(\pi_*(F))$?
It seem that we have a surjective natural morphism $F \to \pi^*(\pi_*(F))$ but how to ensure this is also an isomorphism?

See Hartshorne Exercise III.12.4

Your natural morphism is the wrong way. Have you tried some simple cases, e.g. when X is a genus 1 curve, Y a point and F = O(P) for some point P of X?
